# Comparing data in excel and creating hyperlinks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a function in excel that would compare information from a column in sheet1 with information from a column in sheet2. Basically sheet1 contains information on a specific list of cities and sheet2 is the total list of cities. The idea is - the function needs to see whether any cities from sheet2 are in sheet1 as well. If it finds a match, it has to create a link in sheet2 that would redirect the user to sheet1 where all the information is. Any ideas how to do this? Currently I am lost in all the IFs and brackets.

I’ve tried combining creation of hyperlink with a set of “IF” statements, but all of the attempts failed.

Comment: Using a match formula in the cell, you can find the row location on Sheet2. Then iterate through the sheet using the `cells([match result], column#).value` to assign the `subaddress` for the `Hyperlinks.add` function in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created something very basic, using a simple `Match()` function:

```
=IF(MATCH(A2;Sheet2!A$2:A$4;0);HYPERLINK("www.google.be";A2);0)
```

When the value of "A2" is found in sheet2, somewhere from A2 up to A4, then a hyperlink is created to the best-known URL in the world, and the value you're looking for is displayed. Beware for the dollar-signs in the range `A$2:A$4`, otherwise, dragging your formula to the next row might mess up your formula.